# Como hago esta query (actualizar tabla sql)

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, tablas

Tengo la siguiente consulta :

```
select g.custom_id from tgrupo g, tagente a where a.id_grupo=g.id_grupo and a.nombre like 'tabla'
```

Pillo el custom_id de la tablas tgrupo y tagentes donde el id_grupo de las dos coincida, y el nombre de tagentes sea 'tabla'.

Como hago para que en vez de pillar la la custom_id de tagente pueda actualizar este valor por uno nuevo?

Por ejemplo haciendo ese select me da una custom_id = 3, como puedo actualizar ese valor a 2 por ejemplo.

Comment: ¿El `custom_id`  de que tabla quieres actualizar? ¿de dónde sale el valor 2?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba añadiendo una subconsulta tal que así:

```
update tgrupo g1 set g1.custom_id=2 
       where g1.custom_id = (select g.custom_id 
                                   from tgrupo g, tagente a 
                                   where a.id_grupo=g.id_grupo 
                                         and a.nombre like 'tabla');
```

De esta manera actualizaras la columna que cumpla la condición en el where, en este caso será que actualice la columna 'custom_id' en el que el 'custom_id' sea igual al valor que devuelve la consulta que esta entre parentesis.

Es decir si esa consulta devuelve 3 pues actualizara las filas en el que el custom_id sea 3 y le pondrá de valor 2.

Si consideras que la subconsulta puede devolver mas de un valor en vez de poner un igual debes de poner la clausula IN

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).